# C# Webview2 Margins doesn't work in print function

Tags: c#, printing, margins, webview2

We want to use the print function in WebView2, the Version of Webview2 is 1.0.1108.44. We try to print HTML to PDF. Our expectation is that the image starting from top left without any spaces. Therefore, we try to set the margins in the CoreWebView2PrintSettings, but it seems like no effect on the final result

```
 private async void InitializeAsync()
 {
       WebViewTest.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
       await WebViewTest.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
       WebViewEnvironment = await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
 }

private async void WebView_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //WebViewTest.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");        
    CoreWebView2PrintSettings lPrintSettings = WebViewEnvironment.CreatePrintSettings();
    lPrintSettings.MarginBottom = 0;
    lPrintSettings.MarginLeft = 0;
    lPrintSettings.MarginRight = 0;
    lPrintSettings.MarginTop = 0;
    lPrintSettings.ShouldPrintBackgrounds = true;
    lPrintSettings.ShouldPrintHeaderAndFooter = false;
    lPrintSettings.ShouldPrintSelectionOnly = false;
    await WebViewTest.CoreWebView2.PrintToPdfAsync(PathPDF, lPrintSettings);
}
```

and then we get the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWWoU.png), it still contains a lot of spaces on the top and right sides

The expected print [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOQn1.png) is print with

```
WebViewTest.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
```

It uses windows print, and margins could be set to None, and image starts from top left.

Could you please help us to solve this problem, maybe we have set something wrong? Thank you in advance!

**Update:**
My original way is using HTML file and navigate function of CoreWebView2. In this case Margins doesn't work

```
private string PathHTML = @"E:\Capture.html";
WebViewTest.CoreWebView2.Navigate(PathHTML);
```

Now I try the code from Haldo, and put the capture.jpeg in the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot, load this jpeg with img src and using NavigateToString, then Margins works

```
WebViewTest.NavigateToString(GetHtml());
private string GetHtml()
    {
        return @"<html><body>
          <div>
            <p style=""color: red; font-weight: bold;"">Some text</p>
            <img src=""http://localhost/capture.JPG"" alt=""test image""/><br/>             
          </div>
        </html></body>";
    }
```

The result pdf screenshot is here, [set Margin to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82rV4.jpg) and [set Margin to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am8wV.jpg)

But I still don't know, why in my case the margins doesn't work

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. If noone can give you a good answer, I suggest you report it to Microsoft.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - I get roughly the same margins in both `PrintToPdfAsync` and `Window.print()` (with no margin set). Although I have noticed it doesn't always print with `PrintToPdf` in my testing (in Wpf). Which version of the webv2 runtime are you on?

Comment: Hi @haldo, thank you for your comment, my webview2 runtime version is 98.0.1108.56, which version do you have? Do margins shows the same result in your test? I have also found sometimes it cannot print with `PrintToPdf`, especially when the result PDF is already existing

Comment: I'm using the same runtime - 98.0.1108.56. I was using an earlier version of WebView2 nuget (1.0.1054.xx) but upgraded to the version in your question (1.0.1108.44) but I can't reproduce issue- other than when it fails to print at all (when it does print to PDF the margins are 0 - aligned to top-left of document). Not sure what else to suggest, it seems that printing to pdf is flakey.

Comment: @haldo, could you please upload your code, or do you use the same code as I posted, I will try to find the difference, and I have also test the previous version of its nuget, and get the same result as previous.

Comment: I created a very simple WPF app and uploaded to github [here](https://github.com/haldocalypse/WebView2Demo). It's basically the same code as yours, so not sure if it'll work for you. It might help you find the issue. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Are you using the `WebViewEnvironment` property elsewhere in your code or only to create the print settings?

Comment: Hello @haldo, I'm using WebViewEnvironment only for print settings, I have also tested your code, and put my image as JPEG in the img src as absolute path, now the margin works. Previously, I use HTML file and Navigate function of CoreWebView2 this is the only difference between your project and my project. Please see my update